# R - Passing unquoted alpha-numeric string 123-ARGS-1A1-123456 as argument in function

Tags: r, function, arguments

There must be 50 different questions on passing unquote strings as arguments, but none seem to involve alpha-numeric with hyphens, which appears to be a complicating factor.

I have a large list of text files, named with a hyphenated alpha-numeric strings. All of them start with ###-XXXX but can then be -###-#### or -XXX-XX#### or similar variations, which is to say that the naming convention in the database which creates the .txt files is not fixed. I'm trying to write a function which allows the operator to enter the alpha-numeric part number as as an unquoted string, without appending the ".txt" file type.

```
partData <- function(partNum) { 
dataRaw <- read.table(paste0(partNum,".txt") , 
                    header = TRUE,
                    sep = ",",
                    fileEncoding = "utf-16",
                    quote = ";"
                    )
}
```

This code works as long as the input is enclosed in quotes. In an effort to reduce the chance of input error, I've been trying to remove the requirement to enclose it, so that the operator can simply enter the part number as a string. All of the bquote(), deparse(), substitute() and similar result in a string with extraneous spaces and stripped numbers.

```
bquote(123-ARGS-111-123456)
123 - ARGS - 111 - 123456

bquote(123-ARGS-000-003456)
123 - ARGS - 0 - 3456

deparse(substitute(123-ARGS-000-123456))
[1] "123 - ARGS - 0 - 123456"
```

or errors

```
bquote(123-ARGS-1A1-123456)
Error: unexpected symbol in "bquote(123-ARGS-1A1"

deparse(123-ARGS-000-003456)
Error in deparse(123 - ARGS - 0 - 3456) : object 'ARGS' not found
```

How can I code this unquoted input correctly?

Comment: All R code has to go through the parser. You cannot have arbitrary strings in code that are not included in some quoted character. This is because it needs to have a valid representation in an abstract syntax tree. If you have an expression that is not a valid name, it will be broken up by the parser which happens way before the actual `bquote()` or `substitite()` functions run. You need to quote such values.

Comment: @MrFlick is there any means to extract and re-assmble the individual portions generated by the parser?

Comment: You can convert the ast to a list if you like and iterate it that way. Just is as.list()

Answer (score 0):

If we want to pass unquoted input, use `deparse(substitute`

```
partData <- function(partNum) { 
   partNum <- deparse(substitute(partNum))
   dataRaw <- read.table(paste0(partNum,".txt") , 
                    header = TRUE,
                    sep = ",",
                    fileEncoding = "utf-16",
                    quote = ";"
                    )
   return(dataRaw)
 }
```

If we are passing input with digits as first character, use `backquotes`

```
partData(`123-ARGS-111-123456`)
```

-testing

```
> partData <- function(partNum) { 
    partNum <- deparse(substitute(partNum))
  partNum
}
> partData(123-ARGS-111-123456)
[1] "123 - ARGS - 111 - 123456"
> partData(`123-ARGS-111-123456`)
[1] "123-ARGS-111-123456"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the format of the partNum string. Given the number of existing answers in SO that involve that combination, I did try it before asking. Using substitute, like deparse and bquote examples above, adds extraneous spaces on both sides of the hyphens, and strips characters. I'll edit my question to include that.

Comment: Without trying to sound obnoxious here, what is the difference then between enclosing it in quotes vs. backquotes? My question, perhaps poorly communicated, centers around being able to enter the partNum argument as an unquoted string. Perhaps passing a string in this format as unquoted is simply not possible.

Comment: @AndrewM I get that my solution is not solving your problem. thanks. have a great day!

Comment: Appreciate the input @akrun. Perhaps your solution is the only manner in which it works and I need to reframe my expectations.

Comment: @AndrewM np.  If there are no spaces in the input, then the line in the function can also be `partNum <- gsub("\\s+", "", deparse(substitute(partNum)))`

Comment: That one is closer, but falls apart when there are repeating numbers like "123-ARGS-111-003456" which becomes "123-ARGS-111-3456".  It looks like quotes are going to have to be part of it.

Answer (score 0):

I really think this is not a good use of non-standard evaluation to capture invalid symbol names. If you are really going to have to deal with the `-` operator, then you could actually create your own environment to evaluate the expression to treat `-` as a paste operation.

So you could have a helper function like

```
fakepaste <- function(x, xquoted = substitute(x)) {
  ee <- new.env()
  mp <- function(a, b) {
    a <- substitute(a)
    b <- substitute(b)
  
    ex <- function(x) {
      if (is.numeric(x) | is.character(x)) {
        as.character(x)
      } else if (is.symbol(x)) {
        deparse(x)
      }else {
        eval(x, parent.frame())
      }
    }
    
    paste0(ex(a), "-", ex(b))
  }
  environment(mp) <- ee
  ee$`-` <- mp
  eval(xquoted, ee)
}
```

That would run like

```
fakepaste(123-ARGS-111-123456)
# [1] "123-ARGS-111-123456"
```

You do need to pass in an unevaluated expression so if you need to wrap it in another function then you would need to do something like

```
foo <- function(x) {
  fakepaste(xquoted=substitute(x))
}
foo(123-ARGS-111-123456)
# [1] "123-ARGS-111-123456"]
```

This is all conditional on the value you are passing in being a valid R expression. For example this would never work

```
fakepaste(12-34ARGS)
```

because that cannot be parsed.

It would be much easier to a function that would allow for proper character values or quoted symbol names.

An alternative approach would be to collapse the abstract syntax tree generated by the parser. Here's perhaps a more direct alternative

```
collapse_ast <- function(ast) {
  if (is.symbol(ast)) {
    deparse1(ast)
  } else if (is.character(ast) | is.numeric(ast)) {
    as.character(ast)
  } else {
    ast <- as.list(ast)
    paste0(collapse_ast(ast[[2]]), collapse_ast(ast[[1]]), collapse_ast(ast[[3]]))
  }
}

collapse_ast(quote(123-ARGS-111-123456))
# [1] "123-ARGS-111-123456"
```

This code make the strong assumption that all found operators are infix operators with exactly two parameters.

Comment: Appreciate the efforts here @MrFlick. This too comes apart when the the part number has sequential leading zeros at any point. `collapse_ast(quote(003-ARGS-001-003456))
[1] "3-ARGS-1-3456"`  It looks clear that the argument will always require quotes.

Comment: Yes. The parser will not preserve any leading zeros. That’s correct.